# what is wrong in this code (xslt code)

Tags: xslt

This is my xslt  code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="xslTutorial">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="xslTutorial"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xslTutorial">
    <p>
        SUMMERY:<xsl:value-of select="SECTION/SUMMARY"/>
        <br>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position()=2">
            DATA:<xsl:value-of select="SECTION/DATA"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        </br>           
        </p>    

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="C:\Users\Semsema\Desktop\Day 3-XML\ex2.xslt"?>
<xslTutorial>
<SECTION>
    <SUMMARY>I need a pen and some paper</SUMMARY>
    <DATA>I need a pen.</DATA>
    <DATA>I need some paper.</DATA>
</SECTION>
<SECTION>
    <DATA>I need bread.</DATA>
    <DATA>I need butter.</DATA>
</SECTION>
</xslTutorial>
```

and i want the output to be:

```
SUMMARY: I need a pen and some paper

DATA: I need bread.

DATA: I need butter.
```

How can i do this? (what the wrong in xslt code?)

Comment: I suggest going to your local shop to get some bread, none around here. Clean up your question.

Comment: the BR tag is self-closing, you don't need to have an opening and closing BR tag.

Comment: ok but this still have the wrong result

Answer (score 1):

you are not doing an apply-templates on the SECTION, thus any attempt to test "position()=2" will not give you what you want.

Then again, I'm not really sure if this is the output you are after.

```
<xsl:template match="xslTutorial">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="xslTutorial/SECTION"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xslTutorial/SECTION">
  <p>
    <xsl:if test="SUMMARY">
    SUMMERY:<xsl:value-of select="SUMMARY"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <br/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position()=2">
          <xsl:foreach select="DATA">
            DATA:<xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:foreach>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    <br/>           
    </p>    

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Well, there's a lot more wrong than just that, but it's a start. @sama, you really need to pay more attention to this XSLT tutorial you're following because you're missing some pretty fundamental stuff here.